# WebSQL: Sort by column and print associated rows

Tags: javascript, sql, html, web-sql

I have a small SQL database like this:

```
id        name      category
------------------------------
1         name1     category1
2         name2     category2
3         name3     category1
4         name4     category1
```

And I want to format the db using javascript and html like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>category1
        <ul>
            <li>name1</li>
            <li>name3</li>
            <li>name4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>category2
        <ul>
            <li>name2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since I can't nest SQL executions I'm stuck. I fount out how to display the categories but I failed to go further. Here's my javascript:

```
var db = openDatabase('dbname', '1.0', 'DB Name', 2 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM list', [], function (tx, results) {
        if (results.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; results.rows.length > i; i++) {
                $('ul').append('<li>' + results.rows.item(i).category + '</li>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**Edit:**
I finally could nest the two SQL executions and get the correct variables. But somehow I get first every category and after that I get the names (in the correct order). I checked the code a hundred times and can't find the error...

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM list', [], successCallback);
});

function successCallback(tx, results) {
    if (results.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; results.rows.length > i; i++) {
            var result = results.rows.item(i);
            alert('Next Category: '+result.category);
            tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM list WHERE category = "'+result.category+'"', [], successCallbackTwo);
        }
    }
}

function successCallbackTwo(tx, results) {
    for (var i = 0; results.rows.length > i; i++) {
        alert(results.rows.item(i).name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can "nest SQL executions", just put the second query in the success callback of the first query. But this can be done with a single query.

```js
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    // query (might want to add some ORDER BY clause)
    // updated to include nameurl column as suggested
    tx.executeSql('SELECT category, name, nameurl FROM list', [], function (tx, results) {
        // group results based on category
        var grouped = {};
        if (results.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; results.rows.length > i; i++) {
                var record = result.rows.item(i);
                if(!(record.category in grouped)) {
                    grouped[record.category] = [];
                }
                grouped[record.category].push({
                    name: record.name,
                    nameurl: record.nameurl
                });
            }
        }

        // build tree from categories and names
        var $tree = $('<ul />');
        $.each(grouped, function(category, records) {
            var $leaves = $('<ul />');
            $.each(records, function(ix, record) {
                var $leaf = $('<li />');
                var $leaflink = $('<a />', {
                    text: record.name,
                    href: record.nameurl
                });
                $leaf.append($leaflink);
                $leaves.append($leaf);
            });
            var $branch = $('<li />', {
                text: category
            });
            $branch.append($leaves);
            $tree.append($branch);
        });

        // insert tree into page
        $(document.body).append($tree);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much DCoder, your solution works perfectly fine!
Because I wondered how it can be done with a second query I wanted to try it (see edit). What mistake do I make? Thanks

Comment: WebSQL operates asynchronously, if multiple queries are issued at once, result callbacks are fired in any order the engine wants. If you want a specific ordering of the results, you have to implement it yourself by not firing a new query until all the previous queries have returned results.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but can you give me a hint how I can store a second variable beside name (like nameurl for a url-friendly format). Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. It works like a charm - and I've learned a lot today :)

Comment: @DCoder Need Help.. I'm not getting any data from database using webSQl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021013/how-to-access-the-database-using-websql/19021328?noredirect=1#comment28121040_19021328