# How to access the database using WebSQL?

Tags: database, html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I'm develop a web app and I have an existing database.I'm trying to getting the data from database using WebSQL but getting error as "ExceptionReferenceError: tx is not defined "

code:

```
var databaseSync = null;

try 
{
   databaseSync = openDatabase("database", "1.0", "Database", 10 * 1024 * 1024);
   databaseSync.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('SELECT distinct(Subject) FROM Data', [], function (tx, cb_results){
       var len = cb_results.rows.length;
      var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    var row = cb_results.rows.item(i);
      $("#list").append('<li><a href="#" id="">'+ row.Subject +'</a></li>');
          $("#list").listview('refresh');
  }    
      }, function(){console.log("Transaction success");}, function(tx, error){console.log("Error" + error.message);});

   });
}
catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    console.log("Exception" +e );
}
```

Appending the results in the listview but not getting.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var databaseSync = null;
try 
{
   databaseSync = openDatabase("database", "1.0", "Database", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
   databaseSync.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('SELECT distinct(Subject) FROM Data', [], function (tx, cb_results){
      var len = cb_results.rows.length;
      var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    var row = cb_results.rows.item(i);
    results[i] = row;
   }        
      console.dir(results);
      }, function(){console.log("Transaction success");}, function(tx, error){console.log("Error" + error.message);});

   });
}
catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    console.log("Exception" +e );
}
```

Also, why only 2MB database?

-- edit --

OK,  here is an example of a function, as used in a live project:

```
function return_icd10_vwxy_headers(callback)
{
    var results = [];
    session_storage_database_handle.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT  mainid, key, description FROM qicd10vwxy WHERE parent = '0';", [], function (tx, query_result) 
        {
            var len = query_result.rows.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                var row = query_result.rows.item(i);
                results[i] = {
                                mainid: row["mainid"],
                                key: row["key"],
                                description: row["description"]
                            };
            }
            callback(results)
        });
    });
}
```

Maybe you can see something you missed.

Comment: how to get that database data in a listview

Comment: This code works for me- used in numerous projects.  What do you see?  In what browser are you using this?  What does the console.dir give you?

Comment: only Transaction success is showing in console window.. I'm using chrome

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in the table that you are selecting from?  Would it be possible to replicate the database in sqlite and perform the query to see what results you get?